# Connecting an encypted device to a NAS drive

Tags: encryption, connection, nas

I have a Iomega StorCenter ix2-200 NAS drive which allows the connection of peripheral storage devices.

Pretty much any device I have added it has been able to pick up bar ones which have been encrypted, I can't see any options for decrypting these drives from within the NAS and can't see any documentation anywhere with a guide (or saying that you can't).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How have they been encrypted?

Comment: Using truecrypt using a password (not a file), does the algorithm or anything like that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EMC Lifeline (the OS on the StorCenter) doesn't support any form of encryption other than SSL for encrypted browsing of the management interface.

The only possible way of using a Truecrypt encrypted drive across a network would be to either plug the drive into a device that specifically supports Truecrypt (eg a PC with Truecrypt installed), or to use some form of block-level network transport such as iSCSI to then run Truecrypt locally on your computer.